# Converting a vti file to a numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, vtk, numpy-ndarray

I have a 3D geometry (vessels) in **vit** format which I do not have any information about, but I just visualize it with paraview. I do not know how to read and then convert this **vti** file to a 3D numpy array in python. Does anyone know how can I do this conversion?